# NSAttributedString on UIButton

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, nsmutableattributedstring

```
let strNo = "2222555" // size 18, this should be bold

let remainingStr = "Call to" + "\(strNo)" + "Number"
```

Now, in my UIButton, say button, How to set this title "Call to **2222555** number" And i need to change the size according to device, so I have to do it by coding.

**Update**

I need like following image.

[image]

And need to change the size of the title by coding. Above screenshot is from iPhone 7, In iPhone 5 it become bigger and in iPad it become smaller, so i have to set the size of the title according to requirement.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: change the size means -- font size or else

Comment: Yes Font Size..

Comment: No, this is not my answer, the number 2222555 should be bold and the remaining string should be normal, and I need to do it by coding, it can be possible through property section in xcode storyboard, but it will be fixed for every device, thats why i need to do it by coding, so that i can change it according to device, and attributed text font are not simply changed by doing that.

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your attributed string code? Please show what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer by struggling few days. And it is quite easy.

```
guard
            let font1 = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 22),
            let font2 = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 22)  else { return }

        let dict1:[String:Any] = [
            //            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
            NSFontAttributeName:font2,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white
        ]

        let dict2:[String:Any] = [
            //            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue,
            NSFontAttributeName:font1,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
            //            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        ]

        let dict3:[String:Any] = [
            //            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue,
            NSFontAttributeName:font2,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white
        ]

        let dict4:[String:Any] = [
            //            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue,
            NSFontAttributeName:font1,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white
        ]

        let attString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        attString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Call to", attributes: dict1))
        attString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " 2222555 ", attributes: dict2))
        attString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " To Book Your Skip ", attributes: dict3))
        attString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "NOW", attributes: dict4))

        btnCall.setAttributedTitle(attString, for: .normal)
```

And its Working perfectly as expected.